# Text above two images

Tags: android

I want to place one text above two images. I am using the layout given below but the text is not coming on the top.

Any help pls -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/layout"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top">

        <TableRow android:weightSum="100">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/imageText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:typeface="sans" android:text="TWO"
                android:layout_weight="100"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableRow android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/girrafe"
                android:visibility="visible" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="50" />
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/girrafe"
                android:layout_weight="50" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/table">
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/imageText" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:typeface="sans" android:text="TWO"
                android:layout_weight="100"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:visibility="visible" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="50" />
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_weight="50" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: umm..i want to have the text in the middle and the two images as shown by u

Answer (score 0):

try this... 
its simpler...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```